# CPLEX how to abort search based on model in java

Tags: cplex, ilog

How to abort the search of particular model when we are running two models in java . 
Any suggestions on this . Currently when one model is running iam using  oplF.end(); 
Iam using opl.getModelID() to get the ID of the model will this be helpfull in this scenario . 
When iam running multiple models how abort the search of an particular model .

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but have you tried using an [Aborter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjavaopl/html/ilog/opl/IloCplex.Aborter.html)?

Comment: Hi @rkersh , i had integrated cplex into an java application . and at the same time two models are running concurrently  take example A, B . 
how can i identify the models which are running and abort it by identifying them .  .

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a Java program that concurrently runs two different CPLEX models, and you want to abort the search for one model and not the other.  I don't see any other way to do that than keeping track of the CPLEX object that is used to solve these models.

If the two models run concurrently, they must have been created in two different CPLEX objects. By keeping these two objects around, you can abort one and not the other.